# Is there a limitation in number of context which can be opened in Playwright?

Tags: playwright

We are trying web crawl and get contents from multiple pages. I am taking the advantage of async API with Promise ALL which can execute requests in parallel.

Is there a limitation on the number of contexts which can be opened parallel?

```
const fs = require('fs');
let browser;
const batch_size = 4; // control the number of async parallel calls
    (async () => { // main function
        let urls = [];
        urls = fs.readFileSync('./resources/input_selenium_urls.csv').toString().split("\n");
        browser = await chromium.launch();
        let context_size = 0;
        let processUrls = [];
        let total_length = 0;
        for (let i=0;i<urls.length;i++,total_length++) {
            if ((context_size==batch_size)||(i==urls.length-1)){
                await Promise.all(processUrls.map(x => getHTMLPageSource(x)));
                context_size = 0;
                processUrls = [];
            } else {
                processUrls.push(urls[i]);
                context_size++;
            }
        }
         await browser.close();
    })();

    async function getHTMLPageSource(url) {
        const context = await browser.newContext();
        const page = await context.newPage();
        let response = {}
        try {
            await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });
            response = {
                url : url,
                content: await page.title(),
                error : null
            }
            console.log(response);
        }
        catch {
            response = {
                error : "Timeout error"
            }
        }
        context.close;
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Browser contexts](https://playwright.dev/docs/browser-contexts) are cheap to create, but it's not clear whether there is a hard-coded limit on them from the docs perhaps the limit might depend on the browser you chose and your OS resources. I think you might only be able to find out by creating a lot of contexts.